# Strsplit and count occurrences

Tags: r

Is there a way to split a string like this?

```
A1BG\tAAAGGGCGTTCACCGG\t2 A1BG\tAAGATAGCATCCCACT\t1
```

I would like to split by "\" in order to count how many genes are in the file where a gene is in this case  A1BG and how many codes are where codes are for example AAAGGGCGTTCACCGG and AAGATAGCATCCCACT. 
My attempt below hasn't been successful.

```
strsplit(mydf, '\')[[1]]
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You have a tab `\t`.  So you may need `strsplit(str1, "\t")`

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: @akrun Can you please explain why `\t` works as `split`? I was going to suggest `\\t`, but noticed that both of them work.

Comment: @yarnabrina It's a bit surprising, but if you split on `"\\t"` R will look for a literal backslash, followed by a t. That exists in the string, so it can be split. If you split on `"\t"`, R will look for a tab character, which is represented in this string as `"\t"`, so it also works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have a malformed TSV (tab-separated values) table. If you swap the spaces for newlines, you can read it in as a table and don't need to set up your own parsing rules:

```
x <- "A1BG\tAAAGGGCGTTCACCGG\t2 A1BG\tAAGATAGCATCCCACT\t1"
x2 <- gsub(" ", "\n", x)

library(data.table)
DT = setnames(fread(x2), c("gene", "code", "num"))[]

#    gene             code num
# 1: A1BG AAAGGGCGTTCACCGG   2
# 2: A1BG AAGATAGCATCCCACT   1
```

Then you can count how many codes there are per gene like

```
DT[, .N, by=gene]
# or 
DT[, .(N = uniqueN(code)), by=gene]

#    gene N
# 1: A1BG 2
```

or similarly use dplyr's `count` and `n_distinct` functions.

Answer (score 4):

We can try matching on the regex pattern `\b[ACGT]{16}\b`, and then counting the number of matches in the input string:

```
x <- "A1BG\tAAAGGGCGTTCACCGG\t2 A1BG\tAAGATAGCATCCCACT\t1"
matches <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\b[ACGT]{16}\\b", x, perl=TRUE))[[1]]
length(matches)

[1] 2
```

If the number of base pairs in a gene might not be exactly 16, then try choosing a gene length which would result in the correct count in that case (e.g. between 10 and 20 base pairs).

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
str_count(str1, "[ACGT]{16}")
#[1] 2
```

---

If we are splitting, then split at tab (`\t`)

```
strsplit(str1, "\t")
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "A1BG\tAAAGGGCGTTCACCGG\t2 A1BG\tAAGATAGCATCCCACT\t1"
```